# Export CSV file from codeignitor

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I'm attempting to export a CSV file from a codeignitor project; however, the function opens a new browser tab with no file downloads.

This is the function of the controller.

```
function csvExport($section, $account, $from, $to){
            $balance = $this->m->excel_data($section, $account, $from, $to);
            //var_dump($balance->result());
// Format data for CSV file
            $data = array();
            foreach ($balance->result() as $row) {
                $worker_id = $row->a_id;
                $hour_value = $row->hour;
                if (!isset($data[$worker_id])) {
                    $data[$worker_id] = array(
                        'name' => $row->a_name,
                        'totals' => array()
                    );
                    for ($i = 0; $i < 24; $i++) {
                        $hour = str_pad($i, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) . ':00:00';
                        $data[$worker_id]['totals'][$hour] = 0;
                    }
                }
                $data[$worker_id]['totals'][$hour_value] += $row->workerpcs;
            }
            //  var_dump($data);
// Export to CSV file
            $filename = 'worker_data.csv';
            header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$filename);
            header("Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8");

            $output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
            fwrite($output, "\xEF\xBB\xBF"); // Add UTF-8 BOM
            fputcsv($output, array_merge(array('Worker Name'), array_keys($data[array_key_first($data)]['totals'])));
            foreach ($data as $worker_id => $row) {
                $csv_row = array($row['name']);
                foreach ($row['totals'] as $hour => $value) {
                    $csv_row[] = $value;
                }
                fputcsv($output, $csv_row);
            }
            fwrite($output,""); //Encode UTF-8 BOM in file pointer.

            fclose($output);

            if ($error = error_get_last()) {
                // Handle error
                echo $error;
            }

            exit();
        }
```

`
This is Model

```
function excel_data($section, $account, $from, $to) {
        $this->db->select('a.a_id, a.a_name, DATE_FORMAT(p.pro_date, "%H:00:00") as hour, 
SUM(p.pro_qty) as workerpcs');
        $this->db->from('accounts a');
        $this->db->join('employees e','e.emp_a_id = a.a_id','LEFT');
        $this->db->join('production_report p','p.pro_account_id = a.a_id');
        $this->db->join('stages s','s.st_id = p.pro_stage_id');
        $this->db->order_by("a_name", "ASC");
        $this->db->group_by("a.a_id, hour");

        if ($section != "null") {
            $this->db->where('e.emp_sec_id', $section);
        }
        if ($account != "null") {
            $this->db->where('e.emp_a_id', $account);
        }
        if ($from != "null") {
            $fromdatetime = new DateTime($from);
            $this->db->where('p.pro_date >=', $fromdatetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
        }
        if ($to != "null") {
            $todatetime = new DateTime($to);
            $this->db->where('pro_date <=', $todatetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
        }

        return $this->db->get();
    }
```

I used `vap_dump()` to inspect the contents and discovered data returned from the model function and the data array. I'm not sure what's going on here.

Comment: By comment this like i found the file export but the column name not exporting, so the error in this line             `fputcsv($output, array_merge(array('Worker Name'), array_keys($data[array_key_first($data)]['totals'])));`

Answer (score 0):

The error came from the generation of column name while insert into the CSV.

The controller modified to the following code

```
$balance = $this->m->excel_data($section, $account, $from, $to);
            $data = [];
            foreach ($balance->result() as $row) {
                $worker_id = $row->a_id;
                $hour_value = $row->hour;

                if (!isset($data[$worker_id])) {
                    $data[$worker_id] = [
                        'name' => $row->a_name,
                        'totals' => [],
                    ];
                    for ($i = 0; $i < 24; $i++) {
                        $hour = sprintf('%02d:00:00', $i);
                        $data[$worker_id]['totals'][$hour] = 0;
                    }
                }

                $hour = sprintf('%02d:00:00', $hour_value);
                $data[$worker_id]['totals'][$hour] += $row->workerpcs;
            }

            $filename = 'worker_data.csv';
            header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
            header("Content-Type: application/csv; "); //Set content type for download file.

            $output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
            fputs($output, "\xEF\xBB\xBF"); // Add UTF-8 BOM

            $header = ['Worker Name'];
            for ($i = 0; $i < 24; $i++) {
                $hour = sprintf('%02d:00:00', $i);
                $header[] = $hour;
            }
            fputcsv($output, $header);

            foreach ($data as $worker_id => $row) {
                $csv_row = [$row['name']];
                foreach ($row['totals'] as $hour => $value) {
                    $csv_row[] = $value;
                }
                fputcsv($output, $csv_row);
            }

            fclose($output);
            die();
```